# Instrument a Source.queue

Tags: scala, akka, metrics, akka-stream, codahale-metrics

I would like to have a `Source.queue` (or something analogous to it to push items on a materialized graph) that is instrumented to tell me the current level of saturation of the queue.

I'd like to do that without (re-)implementing the functionality provided by the `QueueSource` graph stage.

One possible solution I came up with is the following:

```scala
object InstrumentedSource {

  final class InstrumentedSourceQueueWithComplete[T](
      delegate: SourceQueueWithComplete[T],
      bufferSize: Int,
  )(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext)
      extends SourceQueueWithComplete[T] {

    override def complete(): Unit = delegate.complete()

    override def fail(ex: Throwable): Unit = delegate.fail(ex)

    override def watchCompletion(): Future[Done] = delegate.watchCompletion()

    private val buffered = new AtomicLong(0)

    private[InstrumentedSource] def onDequeue(): Unit = {
      val _ = buffered.decrementAndGet()
    }

    object BufferSaturationRatioGauge extends RatioGauge {
      override def getRatio: RatioGauge.Ratio = RatioGauge.Ratio.of(buffered.get(), bufferSize)
    }

    lazy val bufferSaturationGauge: RatioGauge = BufferSaturationRatioGauge

    override def offer(elem: T): Future[QueueOfferResult] = {
      val result = delegate.offer(elem)
      result.foreach {
        case QueueOfferResult.Enqueued =>
          val _ = buffered.incrementAndGet()
        case _ => // do nothing
      }
      result
    }
  }

  def queue[T](bufferSize: Int, overflowStrategy: OverflowStrategy)(
      implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext,
      materializer: Materializer,
  ): Source[T, InstrumentedSourceQueueWithComplete[T]] = {
    val (queue, source) = Source.queue[T](bufferSize, overflowStrategy).preMaterialize()
    val instrumentedQueue = new InstrumentedSourceQueueWithComplete[T](queue, bufferSize)
    source.mapMaterializedValue(_ => instrumentedQueue).map { item =>
      instrumentedQueue.onDequeue()
      item
    }
  }

}
```

This mostly appears to work from some manual testing (apart from the fact that `buffered` is at most eventually consistent with the actual number of items in the queue, which should be fine in my case), but I was wondering if there is are solutions that perhaps make better use of built-in functionalities that I might have missed.

Comment: I did almost exactly this recently too. If consistency is not at all a concern, `LongAdder` will have less contention on inserts (I stayed with `AtomicLong`). The thing that bit me was that the overflow strategy matters a lot: `dropBuffer`, `dropHead`, `dropTail` all silently remove elements from the queue when it is full (and return `QueueOfferResult.Enqueued` for new elements), so you end up with a ratio above 1. In our case, we were fine switching to `dropNew` (which returns `QueueOfferResult.Dropped` whenever it drops the offered element).

Comment: This comment is gold, thanks for raising this! You deserve some extra reputation point for this. ;)

Comment: I'm also very curious/uncertain about this question and worry that answering will lead to others _not_ answering. For instance, I'm still a little unclear on exactly whether `Source.queue` is safe to use concurrently (if it isn't, `LongAdder` is likely overkill since the only contention for the `AtomicLong` is at most one concurrent insert and removal).